# A linear function that transforms the set of a quantile distribution to match another quantile distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, linear-transformations, quantile

I'm rebuilding the methods described in the paper [Strong statistical parity through fair synthetic data](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2311.03000.pdf), and on page 3 it describes the following methodology:

> We align both distributions by learning a linear function f which transforms a set of M = 100 equidistantly spaced quantiles of $P(Y | X, S = s_2)$  to match the same set of quantiles of $P(Y | X, S = s_1)$ .

The notation $P(Y | X, S = s_2)$ means - the probability of the outcome Y given X and the variable S is $s_2$.

My question is, **how would I go on creating a linear function be able to transform like this?**

The quantile distributions look like this:

[image]

The last 10 quantile distributions look like this for both groups:

[image]

I've tried interpolation but that doesn't seem right, as it's not a linear function, and linear functions transform part of the data in negative values, which are impossible in probability.

What am I misunderstanding here?

More info, here's the empirical conditional probability distribution of both variables:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know what the notation $P(Y\mid X,S=s_2)$ means.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I've update the question, it's the conditional probability, meaning it has X variables with unknow values and the variable S is $s_2$.

Comment: Hi @parsiad, as I understand, the quantiles here describe are for the percentage of the desired outcome, that means they go from 0 to 1, applying a linear function that would "match" the sets yields values outside of this range, as show in green in the graph. Or I misunderstood where I should get the quantiles from.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with the authors and what is referred is a linear interpolation function, I used the Python Library `scipy.interpolation.interp1d` and ended up with the following result on right:

[image]